# Calculating Average from a CSV File

Tags: java, csv, average

I have a CSV file, format as follows:

`City,Job,Salary
Delhi,Doctors,500
Delhi,Lawyers,400
Delhi,Plumbers,100
London,Doctors,800
London,Lawyers,700
London,Plumbers,300
Tokyo,Doctors,900
Tokyo,Lawyers,800
Tokyo,Plumbers,400
Lawyers,Doctors,300
Lawyers,Lawyers,400
Lawyers,Plumbers,500
Hong Kong,Doctors,1800
Hong Kong,Lawyers,1100
Hong Kong,Plumbers,1000
Moscow,Doctors,300
Moscow,Lawyers,200
Moscow,Plumbers,100
Berlin,Doctors,800
Berlin,Plumbers,900
Paris,Doctors,900
Paris,Lawyers,800
Paris,Plumbers,500
Paris,Dog catchers,400`

I want to find the average of the total salaries.

This is my code:

` import java.io.*;

public class A {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
A a= new A();
a.run();
}

public void run()
{
String csv="C:\\Users\\Dipayan\\Desktop\\salaries.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
int sum=0;
int count=0;
//String a=new String();


        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        // use comma as separator
                    String[] country = line.split(",");
                    int sal=Integer.parseInt(country[2]);
                    sum=sum+sal;
                         count++;
                //System.out.println("Salary [job= " + country[0] 
                                  //        + " , salary=" + country[2] + "]");

                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
                System.out.println("NA");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        System.out.println(sum/count);


        System.out.println("Done");
      }

    }`
```

But, its showing error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Salary"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at A.run(A.java:30)
>       at A.main(A.java:9)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>       at A.run(A.java:46)
>       at A.main(A.java:9)`

Is there any better or short code to parse the CSV file.

Comment: You need to treat the first row representing your headers differently as "Salary" is obviously not a number.

Answer (score 1):

The first line contains the word "Salary" in the third spot. Put `br.readLine()`before the loop and everything should be fine.

You have:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
try {
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Change it to:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
br.readLine()
try {
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: Kindly write the code for that line. Not getting you!

Answer (score 1):

Skip the first line of the CSV file. Do an additional

```
br.readLine()
```

before the while.

You might also want to add some format checks to be sure the file you are reading is in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

`br.readLine()` before the `while-loop` will avoid header line problem, but if your data is not correct you will get same `Exception` again, so, in order to make a safer method you can change this line:

```
int sal=Integer.parseInt(country[2]);
```

With a `try-catch` block to iterate through entire file even if a value is not a valid number

```
int sal;
try {
    sal=Integer.parseInt(country[2]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // if you want here you can show an error message 
    // to give feedback to the user there is not a valid number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a CSV parser - I will use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in this example. I have no affiliation with OpenCSV, it's just what I have in my POM at the moment.

First, create a `class`:

```
public class Salary {
    private String city;
    private String job;
    private long salary;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Now your CSV has three columns, and the header of the CSV matches the property names of our bean, so we can simply use a `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy` to determine which properties to set on the bean:

```
final HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<Salary> mappingStrategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
mappingStrategy.setType(Salary.class);
```

Now we just need to parse the CSV file into a `List` of our beans:

```
final CsvToBean<Salary> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();
try (final Reader reader = ...) {
    final List<Salary> salaries = csvToBean.parse(mappingStrategy, reader);
}
```

Okay.

Now, how do you get an average salary from this mess? Just use a Java 8 `Stream` on the result:

```
    final LongSummaryStatistics statistics = salaries.stream()
            .mapToLong(Salary::getSalary)
            .summaryStatistics();
```

Now we can get all sorts of useful information:

```
final long min = statistics.getMin();
final double average = statistics.getAverage();
final long max = statistics.getMax();
```