# How to read | separated csv file in java?

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

I have pie | separated csv file. I want to read this file in java. I have a java code which read comma separated file in java but it fails at | separated csv file

My file contains "CUSTOMER CODE | PRODUCT CODE | SEND TO BANK | SEND TO BRANCH"
This type of data not comma separated.

Java code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TestPieCSVtoXLs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "D:\\VijayTest\\csvFile.csv";
        DataInputStream myInput;
        String thisLine;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(csvFile);
            myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
            while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
                al = new ArrayList<String>();
                String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
                for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(strar[j]);
                    al.add(strar[j]);
                }
            }
            arList.add(al);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");

change to: String strar[] = thisLine.split("|");

Comment: @Stugal exactly not! A pipe has special meaning in regex and this is presumably why the OP cannot get it to work...

Comment: try escaping it
 
 
String strar[] = thisLine.split("\\|");

Comment: @Stugal..it gives me compailation error...not working

Comment: Just did, I forgot 2nd slash, test it now. I had similar problem some time ago.

Comment: The "unofficial" standard quotes string with the delimiter inside, for example field 1|field 2|"field | 3". I don't know if this is your case, but I'd pay attention to these cases.

Comment: @OP consider using a real CSV parsing library, I have given a number of [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29803289/2071828) in other answers. Your current code doesn't, for example, deal with escaped delimiters or quoted values.

Comment: @Stugal...Thanks its working properly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should change

```
String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
```

to

```
String strar[] = thisLine.split("\\|");
```

Since `|` is a metacharacter in regex, you need to escape it.
Also as stated in the comments, this solutions doesn't take in account special cases...

Comment: @Stugal, damn, for once when I know an answer ;-)

Comment: @Stugal although there is [some debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) on how exactly it should be done it is generally acknowledged that if someone posts an answer as a comment then someone _should_ post that comment as an answer. So, in order not to lose out on the rep, I would recommend posting answers in answers and comments in comments.

Comment: @BoristheSpider roger that.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is good library that can make your life easy while interacting with CSV in java.

Answer (score 0):

code for reading | separated csv file in java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "D:\\VijayTest\\csvfile.csv";
        DataInputStream myInput;
        String thisLine;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(csvFile);
            myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
            while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
                al = new ArrayList<String>();
                String strar[] = thisLine.split("\\|");
                for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(strar[j]);
                    al.add(strar[j]);
                }
            }
            arList.add(al);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) and be done with it:

```
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
    settings.getFormat().setDelimiter('|');

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    List<String[]> allLines = parser.parseAll(YOUR_INPUT_HERE);
```

Its CSV parser can handle all sorts of inputs and is also the fastest CSV parser for Java.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).